# How to change font weight for keywords in VSCode?

Tags: visual-studio-code

It seems keywords are always "bold" in my VS Code and I can't change it, see in the image below the keywords like "class", "extends" etc

[image]

I tried to override the fontStyle for the theme but no luck:

```
"editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {
    "[Darcula Theme from IntelliJ]": {
        "keywords": {
            "fontStyle": ""
        }
    },
},
```

I also have `"editor.fontWeight": "normal"` but it still doesn't affect the keywords...

Any idea how to solve this?
Thx.

Comment: "normal" is not a valid option there, docs says to use "" as "None". The above fonyStyle makes *some* keywords to be not bold, for example the "var" keyword, but the "class" keyword still stays in bold...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The theme is defined at https://github.com/kevinvn1709/vscode-dracula-color-theme/blob/master/themes/dracula-color-theme.json, and you need to override all scopes with value `"bold"`.

```json
"editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {
    "[Darcula Theme from IntelliJ]": {
        "textMateRules": [
            { "scope": "strong", "settings": { "fontStyle": "" } },
            { "scope": "constant.language", "settings": { "fontStyle": "" } },
            { "scope": "storage.type", "settings": { "fontStyle": "" } },
            { "scope": "storage.modifier", "settings": { "fontStyle": "" } },
            { "scope": "keyword",    "settings": { "fontStyle": "" } },
            { "scope": "keyword.control",    "settings": { "fontStyle": "" } },
            { "scope": "variable.language", "settings": { "fontStyle": "" } }
        ]
    }
}
```

[image]

Code from https://www.rosettacode.org/wiki/Greatest_element_of_a_list#Java

Comment: The above didn't solve all issues, these scopes seems to be doing the trick: "keyword", "keyword.control", "constant.language", "storage.modifier", "storage.type", "variable.language"
If you want to update your answer with these I'll happily accept your answer

Comment: It works fine on my environment and I added a screenshot of it. Can you tell me when it doesn't work?

Comment: It doesnt work for the "this" and "super" keywords (for Dart), "variable.language" fix those

Comment: I see, I've fixed the answer.